# Change summary variables returned by Hmisc summary()

Tags: r

Is there an easy way to get ride of the traditional quartiles returned by `summary.formula` with `method="reverse"` from the Hmisc R library? I would like to get the Mean/SD + Min/Max for each of my continuous variable but didn't succeed. It is possible to pass a custom function call through the argument `fun`, but it doesn't work when `method="reverse"`.

Comment: http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg86002.html -  a thing what you could do is to manipulate the function summary itself and create your own package with a summary2 function :P

Comment: A self-contained example would really help... especially for those of us who are not familiar with `summary.formula`.

Comment: @Gnark I don't really like rewriting Frank Harrell's functions, unless I expect to benefit from his LaTeX exportation backend. Anyway, it's always an option :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  The package author has decided (as he states in the post Gnark linked to) that the minimum, maximum, and standard error are (paraphrasing) *"certainly not descriptive"* of continuous variables by categorical group.

You can set `prmsd=TRUE` in `print.summary.formula.reverse` to get the mean and standard deviation, but there's no way to get the min or max.

```
> Data <- data.frame(y=sample(1:2,20,TRUE),x=rnorm(20))
> print(summary.formula(y ~ x,data=Data,method="reverse"),prmsd=TRUE)


Descriptive Statistics by y

+-+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| |1                                                        |2                                                        |
| |(N=11)                                                   |(N=9)                                                    |
+-+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|x|-0.5382053/-0.3375862/ 0.3093839  -0.1434995+/- 1.1113628|-0.4464168/-0.1677906/ 0.3007129   0.1234988+/- 0.9666382|
+-+---------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It seems we wrote our response quite at the same time... In fact, Harrell uses an internal function called `sfn` which call the `quantile()` function, so I think we can replace this by a call to `range()` to get our results, and overwrite the internal function, no?

Comment: @chl: you can try, but I doubt it's that easy.  The function (or others you use) may expect those three quantiles later.

Answer (score 3):

Arf... I just look at the code of `summary.formula()` in the `Hmisc` package and I can confirm that Mean and SD are indeed computed but not shown when printing on the command line. So, we have to ask for it explicitely when calling the `print()` function, e.g.

```
library(Hmisc)
df <- data.frame(g=sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, rep=TRUE), replicate(3, rnorm(100)))
s <- summary(g ~ ., method="reverse", data=df)
latex(s, prmsd=TRUE, digits=2)  # replace latex by print to output inline
```

which yields the following Table:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be within the Hmisc package? If you have a dataframe of continuous variables you could get the same result with a simple use of the reshape package:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(100),b=rnorm(100),c=rnorm(100))

f.summary <- function(x) {
x <- melt(x)
x <- cast(x, variable ~ ., c(mean, sd, min, max))
return(x)
} 

f.summary(df)
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks! Actually I managed to write something similar, but without `reshape`; your solution looks by far better than mine :)