# Summary variables in Hmisc - Output disappears with PRMSD=True

Tags: r

I'm trying to modify the call on summary.formula. I have seen the posts on the function:

[Change summary variables returned by Hmisc summary()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718497/change-summary-variables-returned-by-hmisc-summary)

I'm trying to include the mean and standard deviation in my table. When I modify my command to include prmsd=TRUE, the data disappears, and I get the error messageL

```
Warning message:
In min(nc[nc > 0]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Below is what I'm seeing. First is the call without prmsd, then the call with prmsd. Any ideas as to what's going on here? Given the error message, I think there's a problem with na.rm=TRUE not handling the missing values properly, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
print(summary.formula(S~Kyph, na.rm=TRUE, data=radio, method="reverse"))


Descriptive Statistics by S

+----+---+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|    |N  |Guru Teg Bahadur Hospital |St. Stephens Hospital  |VIMHANS Hospital       |
|    |   |(N=37)                    |(N=1)                  |(N=75)                 |
+----+---+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|Kyph|109|13.6625/20.7100/29.1325   |11.6400/11.6400/11.6400| 0.0000/ 9.6200/17.1650|
+----+---+--------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+


print(summary.formula(S~Kyph, na.rm=TRUE, data=radio, method="reverse"), prmsd=TRUE)


Descriptive Statistics by S

+----+---+--------------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|    |N  |Guru Teg Bahadur Hospital |St. Stephens Hospital |VIMHANS Hospital |
|    |   |(N=37)                    |(N=1)                 |(N=75)           |
+----+---+--------------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|Kyph|109|                          |                      |                 |
+----+---+--------------------------+----------------------+-----------------+

Warning message:
In min(nc[nc > 0]) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Comment: Could you provide summaries and structures of S and Kyph? summary(radio$S), summary(radio$Kyph), str(radio$S), str(radio$Kyph). I suspect it's a problem with these data rather than Hmisc.

Comment: I would suspect the group with one sample - SD might have an issue there. Do you get the same error if all groups have at least two elements?

Comment: I tried to get `summary.formula` to exhibit the missing output problem by passing a dataset with only one member in one of the categories and was unable to replicate. Versions: rms_3.1-0   Hmisc_3.8-3. The warning suggests that the single element might have had an NA value.